# In oracle 19c ,what is the maximum number of columns allowed in a table?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

In oracle 11g, the limit is 1,000 columns per table. Is it the same in 18 and 19c  or have they increased.

Comment: Why did you tag with oracle18c, if your question is about Oracle 19c?

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if that question is answered in the 19c documentation? [Why, yes it is](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answered in the Oracle documentation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - there wasn't an `oracle19c` tag so I created one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the limit is 1,000 column per table.

see [logical database limit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76)